# Can't hide created UIButton

Tags: iphone, xcode, uibutton, nsmutablearray

I have three UIButtons which display in a random order using:

```
NSMutableArray *indexArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                              [NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake(20, 187, 280, 44)],
                              [NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake(20, 258, 280, 44)],
                              [NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake(20, 330, 280, 44)], nil];

//Randomize the array
NSUInteger count = [indexArray count];
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    int nElements = count - i;
    int n = (arc4random() % nElements) + i;
    [indexArray exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:n];
}

//Assign the frames
button1.frame = [((NSValue *)[indexArray objectAtIndex:0]) CGRectValue];
button2.frame = [((NSValue *)[indexArray objectAtIndex:1]) CGRectValue];
button3.frame = [((NSValue *)[indexArray objectAtIndex:2]) CGRectValue];
```

For some reason I an unable to hide these buttons after they display a number of items. I have tried for example

button1.hidden = YES; and also
[self.button1.hidden = YES];

Any ideas? Any help would be most appreciated.

Jamie

Comment: You should show exactly how you are trying to hide them... where, in which method? when?

Comment: I have created a small quiz app. Questions are loaded into a UILabel and the answers into these UIButtons from a plist (via NSMultableArray), when a certain number of questions have been answered the result is displayed and the question and buttons should disappear. To do this I use this:

`if ([questions count]== 11) { button1.hidden = YES; button2.hidden = YES; button3.hidden = YES }` . I am confused as to why these UIButtons do not hide though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass tag to Buttons and use below code

```
 for (UIButton *btn in [self.view subviews]) 
    {
        if (btn.tag==1)
        {
            [btn removeFromSuperview];
        }
   }
```

and your problem will be resolved and revert me..

Answer (score 0):

These buttons are IBOUTLET?

You can think of another way to hide

like, '[UIView viewWithTag:(NSInteger)]

sample code is here

```
UIButton *tmpBtn = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:1]; // tag is your choice
tmpBtn.hidden = YES
```

Answer (score 0):

> To do this I use this:
>
> ```
>  if ([questions count]== 11)
>    { button1.hidden = YES; button2.hidden = YES; button3.hidden = YES }
> ```

I would suggest you check two things:

1. that you effectively take the branch;
2. that your `button*` variables are not `nil`.

e.g.:

```
 if ([questions count]== 11)
 {
    NSLog(@"Enter branch with %x, %x, %x", button1, button2, button3);
    button1.hidden = YES; button2.hidden = YES; button3.hidden = YES;
 }
```

(ignore the warning that you will get on NSLog).